# When you create an Adapter, the layout is not displayed correctly

Tags: android, android-studio

Code

```
  listView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView=getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_auto_adap,parent,false);
            return convertView;
        }
    });
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/car_item_r"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="#F38C8D"
            android:layout_width="1dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Nisan Teana"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/line"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/chat"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Лайкнуть кампанию"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Result

[image]

The layout is not displayed properly.
What can I do to work properly?

If I use a RelativeLayout, everything works.
What is wrong? I do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio provides you definitely understandable error message on your ImageView :
[image]

So, add a vertical constraints.

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```